# Lifecycle phases in maven multi module build

Tags: java, maven, lifecycle, tycho

I have defined a maven multi modul build where one module is only used to generate sources. It will not compile, test or package and won't create any artifacts apart from the generate source files.

I haven't found a way yet to only execute the phases up to `generate-sources` on the generator module, regardless of the phase I specify when I start the multi module build. There are some solutions for skipping unwanted phases, but this is not a real option as there are just to many of them.

For those wondering, *why* I would want it: The build uses tycho and the fornax oaw plugin and so I had to split the build into two separate pom files and use a multi module build file to execute them "together".

Comment: Answering your question, I'm not aware of such a way. The only suggestion can be to bind sources generation not to `generate-sources` phase, but to `package`, `install` or `deploy` phase (whichever you prefer).

Comment: I'm fine with the usual phase - it's just that the "generation module" should stop after that lifecyle phase, even if the target phase was install or deploy or whatever. I don't need any other output from the later phases.

Comment: How about specifying `pom` packaging on the generator module? I still wonder why you did split it up. I was working on a project where we also used the fornax oaw plugin for code genearation. We just bound it to the `generate-sources` phase in its own profile.

Comment: The "generator module" requires a packaging "eclipse-plugin", which is nonsense in my case, because I do not need the plugin itself, just the generated sources. This mandatory packaging type is forced by tycho, I can't use pom or something else. Tycho needs it to collect the dependencies.

Comment: Tycho is unfortunately not open to other packaging types: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=349115

Answer (score 2):

After seeing your [latest question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064624/maven-disable-dedicated-goals-for-modules-in-multi-module-build/13065966#13065966) I think I might have a solution for you.

I guess that all your `../projectN/generate/pom.xml` has the top pom as its parent but I suggest that you create a special `generate-parent` pom with a special plugin management that will skip all the phases for you.

Create an extra folder called `generate-parent` at the top level:

```xml
<modules>
    <module>../generate-parent/pom.xml</module> <!-- NEW FOLDER WITH POM -->
    <module>../project1/generate/pom.xml</module>
    <module>../project1/pom.xml</module>
    <module>../project2/generate/pom.xml</module>
    <module>../project2/pom.xml</module>
    <!-- and many more projects with or without generate sub modules -->
</modules>
```

This new pom will inherit from the parent pom as usual but add only some extra plugin management:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>your-group</groupId>
        <artifactId>your-parent-pom-artifact-id</artifactId>
        <version>your-parent-version</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>generate-parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</name>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-resources</id>
                            <phase>none</phase>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-testResources</id>
                            <phase>none</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-compile</id>
                            <phase>none</phase>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-testCompile</id>
                            <phase>none</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-test</id>
                            <phase>none</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-jar</id>
                            <phase>none</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-install</id>
                            <phase>none</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-deploy</id>
                            <phase>none</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Now with this pom all the default phases are disabled.

Now use this pom in all the generate projekcts. The above pom inherits **all** of the good stuff you have in your parent pom but just adds these special plugin management parts that disables the phases after the `generate-sources`.

`project1/generate/pom.xml`

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>your-group</groupId>
        <artifactId>generate-parent</artifactId>
        <version>your-parent-version</version>
        <relativePath>../../generate-parent</relativePath>
    </parent>

    ...
    The rest of your pom
    ...
</project>
```

This will effectively do what you want, the `generate-parent` is the middle-man that adds all the plugin management you want for just these generate projects.

Answer (score 1):

So far as I understand, this is about using Xtext to create a code generator that is invoked in a maven build. I think you need to split up your project a bit more. You only need the generator to be built, when you change your grammar. So it would be a good idea to have a independent project (not a module) that contains the generator. You build and deploy your generator to a maven repository. In your normal build you use the fornax-oaw-m2 plugin to generate your sources in the `generate-sources` phase as you are doing now. You just need to include the generator as a dependency for the fornax-oaw-m2 plugin.

**EDIT:**
So to come back to your multi module project you want to build: I suggest that there is a module that only contains the resources from which you generate the sources and nothing else. The other java sourcec should be contained in their own module. Then I can suggest two alternatives for using the generator:

1. Run the generator in the module that contains the resources from which you generate the sources and set relative paths appropriately
2. Run the generator in the module that should contain the generated sources and include the module with the resources as a dependency (you may need to unpack that dependency before generating resources)

You still always generate in the `generate-sources` phase. In the 2nd alternative, the configuration of the fornax-oaw-m2 plugin will be duplicated, if you need generate sources to a set of different modules. But I think that this is more the maven way, as you only change the project you are currently building. In the first alternative, you would have to declare the dependencies from the modules, where source is generated into to the module that does the source generation. This seems a bit awkward.

Comment: The generator is not in the same problem, it's inside a different eclipse plugin. My project contains the files written in the specific dsl and normal java code. Sorry for not clarifying on that: It is not about building the generator, it's about using the generator to generate java sources based on the dsl files (using xtend) and compiling the whole stuff.

Comment: @Andreas_D I have adjusted my answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: I do not want to distribute the dsl and java files over separate eclipse projects and try to collect the source files afterwards, maybe by defining the target directories in different projects. A project shall contain all files that are needed to build the library (jar). The generator generates java sources and they need to be compiled, jar'd and installed/deployed.