# maven - disable dedicated goals for modules in multi-module build

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build

I use a multi module build file to trigger the build of a rather complex java project. Now I want to create the eclipse project files - but not for all modules. Is it possible to define on a pom, that it shall *ignore* the `eclipse:eclipse` goal?

The modules definition of the multi-module pom, that I call with `mvn eclipse:eclipse` looks like that:

```
<modules>
  <module>../project1/generate/pom.xml</module>
  <module>../project1/pom.xml</module>
  <module>../project2/generate/pom.xml</module>
  <module>../project2/pom.xml</module>
  <!-- and many more projects with or without generate sub modules -->
</modules>
```

Of course the pom is not only needed for creating eclipse projects so I can't just remove the modules that cause trouble with that goal.

The reason for asking: `eclipse:eclipse` executed on the *generate*  modules will change some attributes in manifest files with the effect that the next build breaks. And I'm tired of correcting them manually all the time ;)

Comment: You can comment the project for which you don't need to create the eclipse project files ?

Comment: As I said: I don't want to. Technically: yes, but I'd like to avoid manually editing the build file each time before I do a `mvn eclipse:eclipse` (and reverting the changes afterwards). I'm hoping for a trick to build and create project files without the need to edit any files before and/or afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Maven Profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) for this.

Remove your defined modules and add something like this:

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>full</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <modules>
            <module>../project1/generate/pom.xml</module>
            <module>../project1/pom.xml</module>
            <module>../project2/generate/pom.xml</module>
            <module>../project2/pom.xml</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>eclipse</id>
        <modules>
            <module>../project1/pom.xml</module>
            <module>../project2/pom.xml</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Then when you want to generate eclipse settings:

```
mvn -Peclipse eclipse:eclipse
```

Comment: Clever - tried it and it works! Only that I always have to remember to set the profile to "eclipse" and communicate this to the other developers. It's much better then it was before but I'm still hoping for a trick without using profiles.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Maven Advanced Reactor Options](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/10/maven-tips-and-tricks-advanced-reactor-options/) (since Maven 2.1):

For instance, to target only project1 and project2:

```
mvn --projects project1, project2 eclipse:eclipse
```

to target project1 and all its dependencies:

```
mvn --projects project1 --also-make eclipse:eclipse
```

This provides a standardised way for reactoring multi-mudule projects and does not requires modification in pom.xml.

Comment: Nice! Not the perfect solution for my special case, because I'd have to list a lot of projects with quite long names (+ I'm too lazy for that), so this time I actually prefer the "profiles" trick. But I'll definitely keep this approach in mind. Thanks!

Comment: Just a side note: for a better maintainability, you can write the long mvn command into some Unix/Windows scripts, for example `set-eclipse-project.sh` and `set-eclipse-project.bat` and keep them within your project.

Comment: The projects will be checked out by many people and I'd like to configure the build in a way that allows them to use the plain maven commands without running into problems... scripts and profiles have one thing in common: you always have to remember that you have to use them.